# Install Faenza Icon Theme in Libreoffice 3.6

Tags: libreoffice

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 and I am using the Faenza Icon Pack.In other versions , I could use those icons in the Libreoffice toolbar, but not in this one(Version 3.6).The 3.5 version didn't worked.Can anyone teach me how to install Faenza in LO 3.6?